# how to set "infragistics" carousel panel reference?

Tags: xaml, infragistics

Which reference has `xamcarouselpanel`?

When I build my project I get an error that `igwindows:XamCarouselPanel` was not found.  My code is:

```
igwindows:="http://infraistics.com/Windows"
```

and the error occur in:

```
igwindows:xamcarouselpanel.ViewSetting
```

If anyone has a link to this `dll` please attach it in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should write

`xmlns:igwindows="http://infragistics.com/Windows"`

in xaml in order to add a namespace and you should have corresponding reference in your project.
After you installed the Infragistics on your computer you should add InfragisticsWPF.XX.X reference.

[image: VS 2012 add Infragistics reference]